# Initializers as a way of converting to new types in Swift

Tags: generics, swift, option-type, initializer

I have the following type called `Maybe`:

```
enum Maybe<T>:{
    case Nothing
    case Something(T)

    init(){
        self = .Nothing
    }

    init(_ something: T){
        self = .Something(something)
    }


}
```

I was expecting this code to call my second initializer, to convert an `Int` into a `Maybe<NSDate>`:

```
var c : Maybe<NSDate> = NSDate()
```

No so. How can I make the above code work (as the builtin `Optional` does)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your initializer:

```
var c = Maybe(NSDate()) 
// type of c inferred as Maybe<NSDate>
```

Swift's `Optional` type relies on some compiler magic to allow direct assignment to its `Some<T>` case without explicitly calling an initializer.